# Using Visual Studio Build-in Entity framework code first from database wizard From command line

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I use the MSSQL Management Studio table Designer to construct my database, and typically apply updates to the model daily.

I am currently creating an Entity Framework code classes using the Visual Studio Built-In wizard.

Can I automate the import task using a command line, or T4 templates so it will regenerate my model given changes that I have made?

Comment: Sounds backwards - you're creating the database first, and then creating a code first model?  Why not stick with a code first model and run migrations to update the database instead?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Thanks  using the designer  for the relationships and table structure is more faster and accurate for me .

Comment: Need some more detail.  Do you update your EDMX model based on the existing database?  Because there are plenty of T4 templates out there that will generate you POCO classes for you from the model.

Comment: @BrendanGreen i don't use The "EDMX model" becase  it is slower in runtime and generate a lot o wearied errors in Visual studio so then i have to close and open the  Visual studio after each import the(the EF Code Frist wizard from exsiting DB  ) generate more light weight class for Visual studio in design time (for me) and in runtime for the end user

Comment: Best I've see is this: https://ghulal.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/efgen-exe-a-command-line-tool-for-automatic-generation-of-entity-framework-dll/.  However, I think you'd be much better off taking full code first approach.  I'd bet that it's faster to make updates to your model (if that's your main concern) and gives you as good flexibility to enforce your relationships.  It would also avoid mass changes of your POCO classes (and potential source control issues that would go along with them) and make deploying changes to the database far easier.

Comment: @BrendanGreen The DB structure is very Complexes(Multi level FK  + more than 100 table  ) and have Data (but not operational)  i feel saver making the Change in the Designer and then Generating SQL File For The Db Updates + Using the linq in the code